# Conflicts with 'mgcv:gam' and another package?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm fitting some GAMMs using the 'mgcv' R package. However, when I attempt to include random smooths, I get an error about recursive vs. atomic vectors:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The model syntax is a straightforward GAMM and I know it's correct (I don't need help with the modeling or data structure):

```
m1 <- bam(Prop ~ Group.ord +
             s(Time, bs="cr") +        
             s(Time, by=Group.ord, bs='cr') + 
             s(Time, Participant, bs="fs", xt="cr", m=1, k=5),
             data=data, method="fREML")
```

I think there may be a package compatibility issue and I was wondering if anyone had found any conflicts between mgcv and another common R package (I've already tried `s=mgcv:::s`). Again, this is not about my data structure--I know that's correct. Just wondering if anyone has encountered a package compatibility issue.

Comment: This would be easier if you posted the output of `sessionInfo()`. Maybe this thread has some information, and they seemed to be running into a similar problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551391/running-a-gamm-suddenly-results-in-the-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors

Comment: Specifically the part where you have to specify the xt argument like this: `xt = list(bs = "cr")`

Comment: This is certainly the way you're passing the `xt` component, the solution is in my comment I posted on the [stats.se] Q

Comment: Thank you! The solution was indeed on the Cross Validated post. You have to specify the argument for 'xt' as @sjp suggested.